# android studio "error: can't find or load main class" in Kotlin file's main method

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In my Android Studio project's java module,I used to code java's main method is OK,But when i convert it to Kotlin code ,like this :

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("i am kotlin")
}
```

When i executed it,
the error happend:"error: can't find or load main class".
I have tried to find some way to solve it ,for example:let the main method outside the class,But it does not work.
I want to know whether it is bebcause that my configuration has some problems.
When i use IntelliJ IDEA i build a kotlin project ,the main method is OK.
so what is my problem in my Android studio's java module in kotlin code.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you resolve it ?

Comment: Same issue for me too. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In kotlin, the main function should be outside of a class which didn't work for you. So when you're trying to use the main function of a class it has to be wrapped up by companion object also be annotated by `@JvmStatic`. So the code block will look like this.

```
class AnythingYouWant {

    companion object {
       @JvmStatic
       fun main(args: Array<String>) {
          println("i am kotlin")
       }
    }
}
```

Another thing to remind you that,

> The main method isn't the entry point in Android like in Java

because it uses completely different build configuration in Android Studio project than the IntelliJ project.

Comment: yes ,i have tried this way to execute the Main method ,but what a pity ,It still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks anyway  ,I may wait to other method